# How can I swap the first and last digits of a number in Java using for for-loops?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, numbers, swap

This is my code (which is not working) without using loops.

```java
System.out.println("Enter a five digit number: ");
int number = scanner.nextInt();

int lastDigit = number % 10;            //by using the % operator, we are able to retrieve the last digit of the number

int firstDigit = number;
while(firstDigit > 9) {
    firstDigit /= 10;
}
//======================================================//
System.out.println("The first digit of the number is " + firstDigit);
System.out.println("The last digit of the number is " + lastDigit);

String string = Integer.toString(number);

char first = string.charAt(0);
char last = string.charAt(string.length() - 1);

string.replace(first, last);
string.replace(last, first);

System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: You should use any loop (like while) or only for is allowed ?

Comment: [`String.replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)) returns a new `String` if there are changes

Comment: @b.GHILAS only for loops are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method to swap the digits using `for` loop:

```java
static int swapDigits(int x) {
    System.out.print(x + " -> ");
    int sign = Integer.signum(x);
    x *= sign;  // invert negative number if necessary

    int last = x % 10;
    int n = x / 10;
    int s = 0;       // sum for the digits in the middle
    for (int p = 1; n > 10; n /= 10, last *= 10, p *= 10) {
        s += p * (n % 10);
    }
    return sign * (10 * (last + s) + n); // restore the sign and get swapped digits
}
```

Tests:

```java
System.out.println(swapDigits(12345));  // 12345 -> 52341
System.out.println(swapDigits(607081)); // 607081 -> 107086
System.out.println(swapDigits(98760));  // 98760 -> 8769  // leading 0 lost
System.out.println(swapDigits(-12345)); // -12345 -> -52341
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually skip all the loops here and use `strings`.

Like this:

```java
public static int swapNr(int nr)
{
    String nrStr = String.valueOf(nr); // Turning our nr into a String

    char[] charArr = nrStr.toCharArray(); // Getting the char Array out of it

    char firstNr = charArr[0]; // Getting the first character
    char lastNr = charArr[charArr.length - 1]; // Getting the last one
    
    // Changing their places
    charArr[0] = lastNr;
    charArr[charArr.length - 1] = firstNr;
    
    return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(charArr)); // Turning the String into an Integer again
}
```

`String.replace()` would not be the correct way to change the place of a specific character in a `String`. And you must know that `Strings` are immutable, that means that when you call `.replace()`, the function returns a new `String` and does not update the current one.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the instructor, converting the number to a string would be too easy, so it is preferred to do it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier not to use for-loops.

```
static int swapFirstAndLastDigit(int n) {
    return Integer.parseInt(("" + n)
        .replaceFirst("^(-)?(.)(.*)(.)$", "$1$4$3$2"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(swapFirstAndLastDigit(12345));
    System.out.println(swapFirstAndLastDigit(-54321));
}
```

output:

```
52341
-14325
```

Comment: The purpose of the exercise is to swap the first digit with the last digit, not reverse the entire number.

Comment: @Gas-AndrewChedid And where is the entire number reversed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this completely without loops, using only arithmetic:

```java
    public static int swap(int v) {
        final int lastDigit = v % 10;
        // the number of digits - 1 (1 digit = 0, 2 digits = 1, ...)
        final int digitsMinusOne = (int) Math.floor(Math.log10(v));
        // the multiplier used for getting/setting the first digit
        // examples:
        // 1234, digitsMinusOne=3, multiplier = 10^3 = 1000
        // 827382, digitsMinusOne=5, multiplier = 10^5 = 100000
        final int multiplier = (int) Math.pow(10, digitsMinusOne);
        // the first digit can be retrieved by dividing by the multiplier
        // for example:
        // 1234 / 1000 = 1
        // 827382 / 100000 = 8
        final int firstDigit = v / multiplier;
        

        // replacing the last digit with the first digit
        v = (v - (v % 10)) + firstDigit;
        // replacing the first digit with the last digit
        v = (v - (firstDigit * multiplier)) + (lastDigit * multiplier);

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method to swap the first and last digit without using any library. Only loops and conditions:

```
static void reverseFirstAndLastDigits(int n) {
    //assigning number to n because after dividing n is gonna be 0
    // and we are needed to use original number for calculation
    int number = n;
    int mertebeler = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        n = n / 10;
        count++;
    }
    //mertebeler = (int) Math.pow(10, count - 1);
    //I can use this for loop instead of Math.pow
    for(int j=1; j<count; j++){
         mertebeler = mertebeler*10;
    }
    int firstNum = number / mertebeler;
    int lastNum = number % 10;
    int newNum = lastNum * mertebeler + (number - (firstNum * mertebeler + lastNum)) + firstNum;
    if (number % mertebeler == 0 ) {
        for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.print("0");
        }
        System.out.println(firstNum);
    }else if(number % 10 == 0){
        System.out.print("0" + newNum);
    }
    else System.out.println(newNum);
}
```